# TableLayout doesn't work on android lollipop

Tags: android, android-studio, android-tablelayout, android-constraintlayout

I'm using a TableLayout inside a ConstraintLayout and it works perfectly on Marshmallow and Nougat but when I'm testing it in Lollipop the application closes immediately and when I remove the TableLayout it works again.

This is my XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.tis_dev.apppoint.Principal"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_principal"
android:background="#F6F6F6"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

<TableLayout

    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tabla1"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:stretchColumns="2,6,8"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">

    <!-- My TableRows here -->

    </TableLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm using Android Studio 2.3.2

Comment: What is in your error stack?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getVisibility()' on a null object reference

Comment: Please add your java code for this activity.